# Taskjuggler - Resource name in taskreport

Tags: project

Ho can I make the resource names appear in the task reports? There is a column 'resources' that I simply use as such:

```
taskreport overview "" {
  scenarios plan
  columns bsi { title 'WBS' },
  name, start, end, resources, chart { width 1400 ${TaskTip} }
  period 2021-07-30 +9m
}
```

However, this will put the resource ID and the name in it. E.g. if I have a resource like:
`resource w1 "Worker One" {}`
the column will contain "w1 (Worker One)".

But I just want the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to the resources column specification. This does the trick:

resources { listitem "<-query attribute='name'->" }

Comment: Thanks! With this I finally also understood how these ominous expressions in TJ work :)